# Defining a Cloud Run service in terraform with Docker image in another projects GCS bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam

I am currently terraforming a GCP project (lets call it project B) which needs access to Docker images stored in another GCP project (project A). It looks roughly like the following:

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = "project-B-sa.json" # authentication
}


# ---- Service Account
resource "google_service_account" "cloud_run_sa" {
  account_id = "cloud-run-sa"
}

# ---- Cloud Run service
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "cloud_run_service" {
  name = "cloud-run-service"
  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/project-A/docker-image:latest"
      }
      service_account_name = google_service_account.cloud_run_sa.email
    }
  }
}
```

I have granted both "Storage Object Viewer" and "Storage Legacy Bucket Reader" for the whole project B service account and the Cloud Run service account, but `terraform apply`ing times out after one minute and greets me with following error message:

```
Error: Error waiting to create Service: resource is in failed state "Ready:False", message: Revision 'cloud-run-service-n6hzp' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. Google Cloud Run Service Agent must have permission to read the image, gcr.io/project-A/docker-image:latest. Ensure that the provided container image URL is correct and that the above account has permission to access the image. If you just enabled the Cloud Run API, the permissions might take a few minutes to propagate. Note that the image is from project [project A], which is not the same as this project [project B]. Permission must be granted to the Google Cloud Run Service Agent from this project.
```

How can I access the docker images stored in the bucket in project A from project B?

Comment: Can you check if the service account is added using `gsutil iam get gs://bucket-name`, check whether service accounts  have permission to access other resources required by your application, such as Compute Engine or Cloud SQL.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde I just verified, both service accounts have `roles/storage.objectViewer` and `roles/storage.legacyBucketReader`.

Comment: Grand CLoud Run service agent the permission to pull the image in another project

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere That's what I tried to do, but there must be some missing permission that I can't seem to figure out

Comment: the Google Cloud Run Service Agent needs permission to access the image, so you may need to grant the Storage Object Creator role to the service account if the image is stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. Additionally, if the image is stored in a private registry, you will need to grant the Service Account Token Creator role to the service account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project B has a hidden Service Account called "Cloud Run Service agent" with email suffix `@serverless-robot-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. You can only see it after toggling "Include Google-provided role grants" on the top left of the IAM admin panel.

This account needs "Storage Object Viewer" on the artifacts bucket in project A.

Source: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying#other-projects